# Actionscript 3.0: Referencing functions from other classes

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I'm a little confused on referencing functions from classes outside of the one referencing it. I always thought that if a function is a public function, I could just go ahead and run it from another class. For example...

I'm trying to run an audio slider bar in my new game. The music comes on just fine when I begin the game. Unfortunately, my gameScreen class subclasses the document class. This means that my audio clip is currently not added to the stage until I begin the game. I want the user to be able to turn the sound off BEFORE playing the game though (yes, even though it's not yet playing, I figure this is a good practice to get into). This means, if they go directly to the options screen, I need my audio slider to be there! Right now, it is only added to the stage if I begin playing though.

My plan to fix this was to go into my options screen class and then if the options screen function is run, it adds the audio clip to the stage. That means I have to run an eventlistener. In this eventlistener, I wanted to reference a function from my `Volume()` class....basically `addToStage`. I already have that in my `Volume()` class and I thought that it is probably a waste of time to get in the habit of copying functions from one class to another when it's already there. So I thought, hey, lets just go to that function since it's a public function!

Turns out I get an error "undefined property addToStage."

So what can I do to make it so I don't have to recopy this function straight into my optionScreen class? Thanks, and I'll provide some code below

```
package {

        import flash.display.Sprite;
        import flash.display.Graphics;
        import flash.events.MouseEvent;
        import flash.events.Event;
        import flash.net.URLRequest;
        import flash.media.Sound;
        import flash.media.SoundChannel;
        import flash.media.SoundTransform;
        import flash.geom.Rectangle;

        public class Volume extends Sprite {

                public var snd:Sound = new Sound();
                public var channel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
                //URLRequest=new URLRequest("solitude.wav");
                //Make sure you pass URLRequest an audio file on your computer.
                public var req:BackgroundMusic = new BackgroundMusic();
                public var boundary:Rectangle;
                public var sprite:Sprite;
                public var slider:Sprite;
                public var xPos:Number;
                public var yPos:Number;
                public var vol:Number;

                /*
                Our request is loaded into the sound object and plays through
                our channel. Volume is initially set at 50% and passed as a
                transformation to our our channels soundTransform property
                (a fancy way of saying volume). The init() function is called.  
                */

                public function Volume() {
                        channel=req.play();
                        channel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onBackgroundMusicFinished,false,0,true );
                        vol=.5;
                        channel.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(vol);
                }

                /*

                The init function creates and draws a rectangle and circle
                to the stage and centers them based on the height and
                width of the stage. In addition, a rectangle object is
                created to 'contain' the sliding circle, like an imaginary box.
                We pass -100 as the x value because it is added relative
                to our sprite. If we set its x value at 0, or the sprites default x
                value,the boundary would stop and start at the slider sprite. Change
                -100 to 0 in the rectangle object to get a better idea of its use.

                */

                public function onStage(e:Event):void
                {
                    //We remove it immediately so that it doesn't get called multiple times
                    //As the instance is added to the display list tree
                    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onStage);

                    xPos = stage.stageWidth/2;
                    yPos = stage.stageHeight/2;

                    /* Now that we have a reference to the stage, let's go ahead and create our slider */
                    init();
                }

                public function init():void {
                        sprite = new Sprite();
                        sprite.graphics.beginFill(0x999999);
                        sprite.graphics.drawRect(xPos,yPos,200,5);
                        sprite.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(sprite);
                        sprite.x-=sprite.width/2;
                        slider = new Sprite();
                        slider.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
                        slider.graphics.drawCircle(xPos,yPos, 20);
                        slider.graphics.endFill();
                        addChild(slider);
                        slider.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragSlider);
                        stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopSlider);
                        boundary=new Rectangle(-100,0,200,0);
                }

                /*

                dragSlider runs when the use holds the mouse button down. A
                startDrag method is used on our sprite where we specify boundary
                as our dragging limits. A new event handler designed
                to change the mouse volume is subsequenlty called per frame, where
                the slider.x property determines volume.

                */

                public function dragSlider(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        slider.startDrag(false,boundary);
                        slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, dragSlider);
                        slider.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, changeVolume);
                }

                /*

                Stops dragging and removes the event listener to save on space. Again,
                volume will be based on the sliders current x position, which is
                constantly being recalculated per frame because we used an
                ENTER_FRAME event.

                */

                public function stopSlider(event:MouseEvent):void {
                        slider.stopDrag();
                        slider.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopSlider);
                }

                /*

                This function is constantly recalculating the vol variable
                based on the sliders x position, relative to the length of
                our rectangle. Creates a decimal range from 0 to 1, where 1
                represents 100% volume and 0 represents mute. Anything exceeding
                100% causes distortion.

                */

                public function changeVolume(event:Event):void {
                        vol=.5+Math.round(slider.x)/200;
                        channel.soundTransform=new SoundTransform(vol);
                }

                public function onBackgroundMusicFinished(event:Event):void
                {
                    channel = req.play();
                    channel.addEventListener( Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onBackgroundMusicFinished );
                }

        }

}
```

OptionScreen class

```
   package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.net.SharedObject;


public class OptionScreen extends MovieClip {

    public var mainMenuButton:SimpleButton;
    private var new_Volume:Volume;

    public function OptionScreen() {

        Mouse.show();
        new_Volume = new Volume();
        new_Volume.onStage();
            mainMenuButtonOptions.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClickMainMenu,false,0,true);
        }

        public function onClickMainMenu(mouseEvent:MouseEvent):void
        {
            dispatchEvent( new NavigationEvent(NavigationEvent.MAINMENU));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Only post the code relevant to the question. SO is not a forum.

Comment: Also, where is `addToStage` defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Public functions are only accessible on an instance that's already instantiated in memory.

For example:

```
var redBall:Ball = new Ball();
redBall.bounce();
```

This works, because I have an instance of `Ball` in memory, and a valid path to the method contained in it.  If I omitted the instance, It would throw an error.

If you want to call a method on a class without instantiating that class, you need a static method.

```
package {   
    public class Ball {
        public static bounce():String {
            return "boing!"
        }
    }
}
```

Now that the method is static, I can call the method on the class directly, rather than an instance of that class.

```
Ball.bounce() // traces "boing!"
```

Comment: Hmm ok...I think I have progressed and almost understand what you're saying.... I changed what I've done in the optoins class in my main question body. It's either saying I don't have enough input arguments (for what I have) or if I put one in, it spits an error back too. What would I put in the parenthesis? e? No doesn't like that either....I don't know what kind of input argument it's looking for

Comment: What Atriace is saying (in engligh) is that your object does not exist until you use `new`. Also, using `static` means that the vars/function reside in the class entity, and not in the instance. The instance is the object you create when you use `new`.

Comment: I recommend turning on "Permit Debugging" (http://www.edchipman.ca/assets/blog/2008-08-09/publishsettings.png).  This will tell you what line on your code is having issues.  Furthermore, try compiling in debug mode by holding Ctrl+Shft+Enter.  The method you called apparently requires more arguments than you passed.  Example `myFunc()` may require two arguments, so I'd fix that by calling `myFunc(arg1, arg2)`.  That's an external issue (not internal to the function).  `e:Event` simply labels the argument variable, and is a matter of practice.  You can easily name your event var `myEvent:Event`

Comment: Hmm ok, well it looks like it worked thanks, although now it's causing another error in my game and I have no idea why.

Comment: More than likely, anywhere else you're calling that function needs to be converted from instance.method() to Class.method() calls. Also (if I recall correctly) non-static methods needs to explicitly call the method even if its in the same class.  Just a hunch.